# arraylist.contains(string) not evaluating string

Tags: java, string, arraylist, contains, evaluate

Strangely enough, I have a feeling I'm missing something here with using ArrayList.contains(Object o), but it's not coming to me right at the moment, can someone point me in the right direction?

I have two ArrayList that contain a list of values.  I want to compare them and get the count of the matches in the files, so I have done this:

```
ArrayList<String> policyNumbersBene = new ArrayList<String>();
policyNumbersBene.add("YOOHOO");
ArrayList<String> policyNumberDly = new ArrayList<String>();
policyNumberDly.add("YOOHOO");

int count = 0;
for (String policyNumber : policyNumbersBene) { // compare 2 arraylists to each other.
    count += (policyNumberDly.contains(policyNumber) ? count : 0;
}
'SYSO'(count);
```

I believe I should get 1 in the output of the counter, but I am getting 0 each time.  When I slapped a debugger on there, I can see the list of values in the arrays, and I see "YOOHOO" in there.  Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?  I feel like a complete java newbie asking this.

Comment: First iteration, `count += count` => 0;

Comment: OMG I'm such an idiot... dude, +1 for you.... I cannot believe I compeltely missed that... :: Face palm ::

Comment: How could `if (policyNumberDly.equals(policyNumber))` ever return true since those are not instances of same class (`ArrayList<String>` vs `String`)?

Comment: @sp00m, you are absolutely right, I edited the post and removed the evaluation as it will never return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute this line, `count` is `0` so you get `0 + 0`

```
count += (policyNumberDly.contains(policyNumber)) ? count : 0;
```

Fix:

```
count += (policyNumberDly.contains(policyNumber)) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I cannot believe that I missed this... Looks like I threw an id10t Exception somewhere over the weekend and never recovered.

Comment: We've all been there, Josh.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, if you needs to calls the method contains, to use an `LinkedHashset` instead of an `ArrayList`.

The call will be in constant time instead of O(n).

Comment: I actually tried this solution and it ran much faster (12s) than comparing the ArrayLists. Thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

```
   System.out.println(policyNumberDly.contains(policyNumber) ? 1 :0);
```

it prints 1 so state count=1;